# How to convert Strings from MySql to JSON array

Tags: php, json

I am trying to convert my data received from MySql into JSON, in following format -

```
[
    {
        "question": "This is a question",
        "options": [
            "Option which may contain double or single quoted text",
            "Option 2",
            "Option 3",
            "Option 4"
        ]
    }
]
```

My relevant PHP code, so far is -

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("select * from test_table limit 5", $db);  
$json_response = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$option_01 = $row['Option_1'];
$option_02 = $row['Option_2'];
$option_03 = $row['Option_3'];
$option_04 = $row['Option_4'];

$row_array['question'] = $row['Question'];

// I am unable to format Options ($option_01,$option_02,$option_03,$option_04) into desired Array as mentioned in starting
$row_array['options'] = "";
array_push($json_response,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($json_response);
?>
```

But I am stuck on **how to make array of option variables, received from MySql database?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `$row_array['options']` an array

```
$row_array['options'] = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   $row_array['options'][] = $row['Option_1'];
   $row_array['options'][] = $row['Option_2'];
   $row_array['options'][] = $row['Option_3'];
   $row_array['options'][] = $row['Option_4'];
}
```

Also, remember that [mysql_ functions are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Thanks. I got it now. Also I am trying to upgrade myself (regarding mysql), but it's taking time. I will accept the answer, once the stackoverflow's time limit is over. For now an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("select * from test_table limit 5", $db);  
$json_response = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$ans = array();
$ans["question"]= $row["question"];
$ans["options"]=$row;
$json_response[]=$ans;
}
echo json_encode($json_response);
?>
```

This will generate same result as you expect but in the option array you will get question fields too. But that can be ignored while working on json result.

Note:- Mysql functions are deprecated in newer versions.